# Google Structured Data Testing Tool Repeat Error: "The URL could not be rendered. Some markup may be missing."

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, validation, open-graph-protocol

When using Google's Structured Data Testing Tool, I consistently get the error:

> The URL could not be rendered. Some markup may be missing.

- I have identified and fixed all of the structured data errors - I have 3 items, all of which have **0 errors**, two of which have **0 warnings** and one of which has **3 warnings**.
- I am using **OpenGraph** vocabulary (both `og:` and `twitter:`) in the first item and **schema.org** vocabulary in both subsequent items.
- I am using `<meta>` elements in the `<head>` to structure the data in the first item and `json-ld` to structure the data in both subsequent items.
- I have checked to see if the document markup validates on **W3 Unicorn** - it does.

Since the markup validates and the structured data is error-free, what does it mean when Google Structured Data Testing Tool consistently informs me:

> The URL could not be rendered. Some markup may be missing.

The URL *could not be rendered* in what sense?

---

**Update:**

After further testing, I have established the following:

1. The error is *definitely* being triggered by the markup inside the `<body>...</body>` of the document.
2. There are multiple (as yet unknown) elements triggering the error.
3. **One** of the errors is definitely the presence of a `<footer>...</footer>` element. A `<body>` which contains a `<header>` or a `<main>` (or both) will not trigger the error, but as soon as the `<body>` contains a `<footer>`, it will.
4. **One** of the errors is an anchor which contains a class (eg. `<a href="/my-page" class="link-to-my-page">My Page</a>`) - when the `class` attribute is removed from the anchor, the anchor no longer triggers an error.
5. **One** of the errors is the presence of one or more `<article>...</article>` elements. As soon as the `<body>` contains at least one `<article>`, it will trigger the error.
6. **One** of the errors is any `<img>` element which references an **SVG**. If the `src` attribute points to a file which has an identical file-path but ends in `.png`, the error is not triggered.

---

**Lightbulb Moment**

- The `<img>` element in 6. points to an **SVG**.
- each `<article>` has a CSS `background-image` which is an **SVG**
- The `<a>` which contains the class has a CSS `background-image` which is an **SVG**
- The `<footer>` has a `::before` and an `::after` pseudo-element, each of which has a CSS `background-image` which is an **SVG**

---

**Conclusion**

*Google Structured Data Testing Tool* doesn't yet know how to process (or just ignore) references to **SVG** files.

Comment: Do you get this error right after entering your URL in the SDTT (before the extracted structured data is shown)? Is your page a plain old HTML document, or do you use JavaScript for showing the content?

Comment: 1) I see this error several seconds after entering the URL in the SDTT. 2) When it appears, the error is overlaid over the top of the displayed extracted, structured data. 3) The page is a plain old HTML document (although after onload, some additional extra markup is added via javascript.

Comment: I have removed the javascript. It makes no difference. The error still appears. I take it the appearance of this error isn't usual then? Can anyone describe what am I supposed to see instead of this error?

Comment: I never encountered this error. Most of the time I’m pasting the markup (instead of letting the tool fetch the URL), though -- but I just tested a few pages via URL and didn’t get any error (the normal behaviour is just getting the extracted data on the right, no overlay). Is it possible for you to share the URL?

Comment: Sure, it's: http://handsoffhri.org/

Comment: I note that if I just copy-paste the JSON-LD into SDTT from the page source, no error shows.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with your page when checking via URL. I’m not sure, but I think the issue has to do with your JavaScript. Maybe while fetching the markup, the tool notices that your JS changes something that affects the already fetched markup, so the tool is no longer sure to get the markup correctly.

Comment: I wondered the same myself, but I've tested the document with the javascript entirely removed and it does not remove the error. Please see my updates in the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After:

- isolating error triggers
- assessing what all the error triggers had in common (they all referred to external `.svg` files)

The answer is:

*Google Structured Data Testing Tool* doesn't yet know how to process (or just ignore) references to **SVG** files.